# Dynamic Binding Path Combobox to Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

In my XAML i have a DataTemplate for an ItemsControl where i have to bind the combobox control to the same Dictionary object.

But i want these comboboxes to display different items, and this difference have to be provided by the dictionary key.

Example, if i write :

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDictionary[Key]}"/>
```

Then the combobox will display all the values given by the specified key. But this '[key]' part has to change for each item present in my ItemsControl.

Is there a solution, including string concatenation, whatever, who could help me to achieve that ? I can't find anything to dynamically build the Path value of my binding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MultiBinding in combination with a MultiConverter to achieve that.

Your xaml

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
    <Binding Path="MyDictionary" />
    <Binding Path="Key" />
</MultiBinding>
```

And the converter could look something like this

```
public class DictionaryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var key = values[1] as YourKeyType;
        var dictionary = values[0] as Dictionary<YourKeyType, YourValueType>;

        return dictionary[key];
    }
}
```